# Recursive SELECT through several tables via SQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a real estate project where the tables are as follows:

1. `apartment` table has a building ID
2. `building` table has a neighborhood ID
3. `neighborhood` table has a city ID

Now if I want to get all the apartments in a certain city, what would be the best way?
I am using `PHP` and `MySQL` and here is what I tried and failed

```
public static function getAllApartmentsInACity ($city_id) {

    $results = array();
    $db = DB::getInstance(); //My DB class nothing wrong here
    $n = self::getAllNeighborhoodsInACity($city_id); // returns an array of objects of all neighborhoods
    $b = array();
    $a = array();

    foreach ($n as $singleN) {
        $b[] = self::getAllBuildingsInANeighborhood($singleN->id); //returns an array of objects of all buildings
    }

    foreach ($b as $singleB) {
        echo $singleB->id . '-';
    }

    return $a;

}
```

After all that I am getting `Null` when I `var_dump` the return from this function, providing that I have data in the tables.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So See about JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query:

```
$query = "SELECT apartment.*
          FROM apartment
             JOIN building ON
                 building.id = apartment.building_id
             JOIN neighborhood ON
                 neighborhood.id = building.neighborhood_id
             JOIN city ON
                 city.id = neighborhood.city_id AND
                 city.id = 'SOME CITY ID'
         ";
```